# LINQ - Previous Record

Tags: linq

All:

Lets say I have the following table:

```
RevisionID, Project_ID, Count, Changed_Date
1           2          4      01/01/2016: 01:02:01
2           2          7      01/01/2016: 01:03:01
3           2          8      01/01/2016: 01:04:01
4           2          3      01/01/2016: 01:05:01
5           2          15      01/01/2016: 01:06:01
```

I am ordering the records based on Updated_Date.  A user comes into my site and edits record (RevisionID = 3).  For various reasons, using LINQ (with entity framework), I need to get the previous record in the table, which would be RevisionID = 2 so I can perform calculations on "Count".  If user went to edit record (RevisionID = 4), I would need to select RevisionID = 3.

I currently have the following:

```
var x = _db.RevisionHistory
           .Where(t => t.Project_ID == input.Project_ID)
           .OrderBy(t => t.Changed_Date);
```

This works in finding the records based on the Project_ID, but how then do I select the record before?

I am trying to do the following, but in one LINQ statement, if possible.

```
var itemList = from t in _db.RevisionHistory
where t.Project_ID == input.Project_ID
orderby t.Changed_Date
select t;

int h = 0;

foreach (var entry in itemList)
{
if (entry.Revision_ID == input.Revision_ID)
{
break;
}
h = entry.Revision_ID;
}
var previousEntry = _db.RevisionHistory.Find(h);
```

Comment: Could you format the code a bit, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct single query equivalent of your code:

```
var previousEntry = (
    from r1 in db.RevisionHistory
    where r1.Project_ID == input.Project_ID && r1.Revision_ID == input.Revision_ID
    from r2 in db.RevisionHistory
    where r2.Project_ID == r1.Project_ID && r2.Changed_Date < r1.Changed_Date
    orderby r2.Changed_Date descending
    select r2
).FirstOrDefault();
```

which generates the following SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[Revision_ID] AS [Revision_ID], 
    [Project1].[Project_ID] AS [Project_ID], 
    [Project1].[Count] AS [Count], 
    [Project1].[Changed_Date] AS [Changed_Date]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent2].[Revision_ID] AS [Revision_ID], 
        [Extent2].[Project_ID] AS [Project_ID], 
        [Extent2].[Count] AS [Count], 
        [Extent2].[Changed_Date] AS [Changed_Date]
        FROM  [dbo].[RevisionHistories] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[RevisionHistories] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent2].[Project_ID] = [Extent1].[Project_ID]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Project_ID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Revision_ID] = @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent2].[Changed_Date] < [Extent1].[Changed_Date])
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Changed_Date] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

hope I understood what you want.
Try:

```
var x = _db.RevisionHistory
       .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Project_ID == input.Project_ID && t.Revision_ID == input.Revision_ID -1)
```

Or, based on what you wrote, but edited:

```
_db.RevisionHistory
   .Where(t => t.Project_ID == input.Project_ID)
   .OrderBy(t => t.Changed_Date)
   .TakeWhile(t => t.Revision_ID != input.Revision_ID)
   .Last()
```

Comment: My apologies, but I do not think I explained it well enough.  The table will have many projects (Project_ID) values, so I do not want the previous Project_ID.  Inside the recordset based on this query (SELECT * FROM RevisionHistory WHERE Project_ID = 15 ORDER BY Changed_Date), a user might select the 7th record to edit inside the UI.  I would like to return the 6th record in that recordset, because it would be the previous record.  Hopefully that makes more sense?

Comment: I've edited the answer. Have I understood the problem well?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be doing as I hoped, but I know I am not doing a great job explaining, so thank you but my apologies.  If you look at the table above, if the user is editing Revision_ID = 4, I need to get back record Revision_ID = 3.  If the user is editing Revision_ID = 5, I need to return Revision_ID 4.  The Revision_IDs are not always in order like the table above, but based on the WHERE clause for Project_ID and ORDER BY Change_Date, I get a list like something above.

Comment: var itemList = from t in _db.Card_Revision_History
                           where t.Project_ID == input.Project_ID
                           orderby t.Changed_Date
                           select t;
            int h = 0;

            foreach (var entry in itemList)
            {
                if (entry.Card_Revision_History_ID == input.Card_Revision_History_ID)
                {
                    break;
                }
                h = entry.Card_Revision_History_ID;
            }
            var previousEntry = _db.Card_Revision_History.Find(h);

Comment: well...if you have the selected revision id, wouldn't this help: 
.Where(t=>t.Project_ID == input.Project_ID && t.Revision_ID == input.Revision_ID -1) [i've edited the reply]

Comment: Presuming it's not a highly distributed and colaborative system that you're trying to make, the changed date and the revision id should have the same 'order'. THis, leading to that what you want is the row with revision id - 1. But, the edited response should be what you need

Comment: If it's what you needed, you could mark it as the correct answer ;)